# Return a value from batch files (.bat file)to a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .bat file shown below

```
@echo off 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('C:\MyProj\Sources\SearchString.vbs') do (
set ScriptOut=%%a)
#echo Script Result = %ScriptOut%
echo %ScriptOut% >C:\ThreePartition\Sources\myfile.txt
```

I want my output variable which is ScriptOut to be stored into a text file.
Can anyone suggest any method to be added to my existing batch file.

Thanks
Maddy

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand correctly that your file gets overwritten and you want it appended? If so, try this:

```
echo %ScriptOut% >> C:\ThreePartition\Sources\myfile.txt
```

(note the double ">>")

Comment: hi,
 No actually i get a value returned to ScriptOut(Returned frm vbs) which should be written into a text file.When i run this above code,i just get ECHO is OFF in the myfile.txt

Comment: Then the blank line is your problem as Johannes Rössel pointed out.

Comment: I didnt get it Johannes??.Which blank line could be the problem.Why am i getting ECH is OFF in my Myfile.txt.??

Comment: The reason you are getting ECHO OFF is that ECHO is being passed noting, or just whitespace (ie a blank line). In this case, ECHO prints whether command-echoing is turned on. (It just so happens that you turned off that with your 'ECHO OFF' at the top) This has no effect on whether it will redirect.

Comment: I elaborated a little more, hopefully that made it somewhat clearer

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop you have there executes that script and runs for every line the script returns. Basically this means that your environment variable `%ScriptOut%` contains only the *last* line of the output (since it gets overwritten each time the loop processes another line). So if your script returns

```
a
b
c
```

then `%ScriptOut%` will contain only `c`. If the last line is empty or contains only spaces iot will effectively delete `%ScriptOut%` which is why when you do an

```
echo %ScriptOut%
```

you'll only get `ECHO is on.` since after variable substition all that's left there is `echo`. You can use

echo.%ScriptOut%

in which case you'll be getting an empty line (which would be what `%ScriptOut%` contains at that point.

If you want to print every line the script returns to a file then you can do that much easier by simply doing a

```
cscript C:\MyProj\Sources\SearchString.vbs > C:\ThreePartition\Sources\myfile.txt
```

or use `>>` for redirection if you want the output to be appended to the file, as [Stanislav Kniazev pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737098/return-a-value-from-batch-files-bat-fileto-a-text-file/737146#737146).

If you just want to store the last *non-empty* line, then the following might work:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('C:\MyProj\Sources\SearchString.vbs') do (
  if not "%%a"=="" set ScriptOut=%%a
)
```

which will only set `%ScriptOut%` in case the loop variable isn't empty.